# A simple variant of Jordan inequality

Tags: trigonometry

I want to prove that
$$ \frac{1}{M^2} \frac{ \sin^2 (M\theta) }{\sin^2 (\theta) } \geq \frac{4}{\pi^2}$$
holds for every $M \geq 1 $ and $ |\theta | \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}] $.
It is a slight variant of Jordan Inequality but it seems that the technique for proving Jordan inequality does not work here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the inequality?

Comment: Sorry I fixed it.

Comment: The inequality doesn't hold when $\theta= \frac{\pi}{2}$, M=4

Comment: Indeed. In general the inequality does not hold for $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{M}$, so the interval must be something like $(0,\min\{\frac{2\pi}{M},\frac{\pi}{2}\})$...

Comment: @Hugh I just verified the errata list for the book I was reading. There was $M$ missing in $|\theta | \in (0 , \frac{\pi}{2 M} ] $. Thanks..

Comment: Now it is just a simple application of Jordan Inequality. Thanks.

Comment: The interval must be open on the right though...

Answer (score 1):

Write $t = M\theta$. Then $ t \in [0,\pi/2]$. Rewrite the lefthand side as

$$\frac{\theta^2}{\sin^2 \theta} \frac{\sin^2 t}{t^2}$$

Since $M$ is free to be any number $\ge 1$, we have that $\theta =t/M$ can be any number $\in [0,t] $. The function $\sin x/x$ is bounded continuous decreasing and positive on $[0,\pi/2]$. Therefore its maximum is $1$ (at zero) and minimum is $1/ (\pi/2)=2/\pi$.

$$\frac{\sin^2 t}{t^2} \ge \frac{4}{\pi^2}  \mbox{ and }\frac{\theta^2}{\sin^2 \theta}\ge 1.$$

This completes the proof.